# jQuery Mobile to detect phone call has been made and then has ended

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I am new to jQuery Mobile.

I am developing an application by which I need to detect if a phone call has been made, by clicking on a hyperlinked phone number in my application.
I also need a hook to detect if the phone call has ended.

Is this possible?

Comment: Like dis: https://github.com/dalyc/Cordova-CallLog-Plugin ?

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting

Comment: show what you have done here.